# Send data to multiple tcp clients at once

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a tcpserver that can handle an undefined number of tcpclients. Whenever the server needs to send data to all clients I use a loop to iterate through all clients to send the data. I was thinking that this loop might perform badly when the number of clients go up. Let's say that 2000 clients are connected then the time to send one data package is going to be relatively long.

Is there any way to send the data to all clients at once without looping? Or is looping the best (and only) way?

Comment: You could improve performance by using Parallel.ForEach. This way, one slow client won't stop your loop .  If it fits within the needs of your program, you could also investigate Multicast networking.

Comment: Or use Async methods and WhenAll for example

Comment: My server already sends the data asynchronously. But my guess is that this would still leave a gap between the time when the first clients receives the data and when the last clients receives the data. Maybe the gap is very small and I'm just worrying for nothing.